# Change text color in ActionMenu. Android

Tags: android, text, colors, android-actionbar

I have this style.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="tst1" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar2</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar2" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]
But how do I change color of the "Start Over" text?
Hoping for quick anwser.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Replace your code with following code -->

<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="tst1" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>  <!-- your textColor here -->
</style>

</resources>
```